# Mapping a function over a sequence of argument vectors in Clojure

Tags: dictionary, clojure

Is there a way to map a function foo of say 3 arguments over a list of vectors(or lists) of arguments so that the vector destructures?

```
(defn foo [a b c]
 ...)

([a1 b1 c1] [a2 b2 c2])
```

Is there a simple function that I can use to do this? Or do I have to construct an anonymous function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the apply function.

```
(map #(apply foo %) '([1 2 3] [4 5 6]))
```

EDIT:

Since you mentioned not using an anonymous function I'll note that you can easily make a 'mappable' version of the foo function with some simple function composition.

```
(def mfoo (partial apply foo))
(map mfoo '([1 2 3] [4 5 6]))
```

Comment: Generally speaking, use vectors instead of quoted lists since the latter will prevent evaluation of the interior parts.